# Yii, ajax, Button. How to prevent multiple JS onclick bindings

Tags: ajax, yii

(First of all English is not my native language, I'm sorry if I'll probably be mistaken).
I've created Yii Web app where is input form on the main page which appears after button click through ajax request. There is a "Cancel" button on the form that makes div with form invisible. If I click "Show form" and "Cancel" N times and then submit a form with data the request is repeating N times. Obviously, browser binds `onclick` event to the submit button every time form appears. Can anybody explain how to prevent it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I've had the exact same problem and there was a discussion about it in the [Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7872-strange-ajaxsubmitbutton-problem-multiple-posts).

This basically happens because you are probably returning ajax results with "*render()*" instead or *renderPartial()*. This adds the javascript code every time to activate all ajax buttons. If they were already active they will now be triggered twice. So the solution is to use *renderPartial()*. Either use render the first time only and then *renderPartial()*, or use *renderPartial()* from the start but make sure the "*processOutput*" parameter is only set to TRUE the first time.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer! I'll post here my final solution when I finish!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
There was two steps:
First one. I decided to add JS code to my CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton instance that unbind 'onclick' event on this very button after click. No success!
Back to work. After two hours of digging I realized than when you click 'Submit' button it raises not only 'click' event. It raises 'submit' event too. So you need to unbind any event from whole form, not only button!
Here is my code:

```
echo CHtml::submitButton($diary->isNewRecord ? 'Создать' : 'Сохранить', array('id' => 'newRecSubmit'));
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('btnNewRec', "
    var clickNewRec = function()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            'success': function(data) {
                $('#ui-tabs-1').empty();
                $('#ui-tabs-1').append(data);
            },
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': '".$this->createUrl('/diary/newRecord')."',
            'cache': false,
            'data': jQuery(this).parents('form').serialize()
        });

        $('#new-rec-form').unbind();

        return false;
    }

    $('#newRecSubmit').unbind('click').click(clickNewRec);
");
```

Hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I just run into the same problem, the fix is in the line that starts with '**beforeSend**'. jQuery undelegate() function removes a handler from the event for all elements which match the current selector.

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
  $model->isNewRecord ? 'Add week(s)' : 'Save',
  array('buckets/create/'.$other['id'].'/'.$other['type']),
  array(
    'update'=>'#addWeek',
    'type'=>'POST',
    'dataType'=>'json',
    'beforeSend'=>'function(){$("body").undelegate("#addWeeksAjax","click");}',
    'success'=>'js:function(data) {
      var a=[];
     }',
  ),
  array('id'=>'addWeeksAjax')
); ?>
```

In my example I've added the tag id with value 'addWeeksAjax' to the button generated by Yii so I can target it with jQuery **undelegate()** function.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my project this way, it may not be a good way, but works fine for me: i just added unique 'id' to ajax properties (in my case smth like

```
                <?=CHtml::ajaxLink('<i class="icon-trash"></i>',
                    $this->createUrl('afisha/DeletePlaceAjax',
                    array('id'=>$value['id'])),
                    array('update'=>'.data', 
                     'beforeSend' => 'function(){$(".table").addClass("loading");}',
                     'complete' => 'function(){$(".table").removeClass("loading");}'),
                   array('confirm'=>"Уверены?",'id'=>md5($value['id']).time()))
                     ?>
```

).
Of course, you should call *renderPartial* with property '*processOutput*'=true. After that, everything works well, because every new element has got only one binded js-action.

Answer (score 0):

text below copied from here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14562-ajaxsubmitbutton-submit-multiple-times-problem/

> common issue...
>
> yii ajax stuff not working properly if you have more than one, and if
>   you not set unique ID
>
> you should make sure that everything have unique ID every time...
>
> and you should know that if you load form via ajax - yii not working
>   well with it, cause it has some bugs in the javascript code, with die
>   and live

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use jQuery.on function. This will fire up event on dynamically changed content. For example: you're downloading some list of images, and populate them on site with new control buttons (view, edit, remove). Example structure could looks like that:

```
<div id="img_35" class='img-layer'>
   <img src='path.jpg'>
   <button class='view' ... />
   <button class='edit' ... />
   <button class='delete' ... />
</div>
```

Then, proper JS could look like this ( only for delete, others are similiar ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.img-layer .delete', function() {
        var imgId = String($(this).parent().attr('id)).split('_')[1]; //obtain img ID
        $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.some.ajax/url',
           type : 'POST',
           data: {
               id: imgId
           }
        }).done({
            alert('Success!');
        }).fail({
            alert('fail :(');
        });
    }
</script>
```

After that you don't have to bind and unbind each element when it has to be appear on your page. Also, this solutiion os simple and it's code-clean. This is also easy to locate and modify in code.

I hope, this could be usefull for someone.

Regards
.   Simon